Pinning down the joint distribution from marginal distributions?
We know that knowing the marginal distributions of random variables $X$ and $Y$ is not enough to pin down the joint distribution of $\left(X,Y\right)$.
But suppose there are three random variables, $X$, $Y$, and $Z$. If we know the joint distributions of $\left(X, Y\right)$, $\left(X, Z\right)$, and $\left(Y, Z\right)$. Is the joint distribution of $\left(X, Y, Z\right)$ uniquely pinned down?

No, it's not. In fact, a perhaps disturbing example is as follows. It is possible such that $(X,Y),(X,Z),$ and $(Y,Z)$ are bivariate gaussian, but $(X,Y,Z)$ is not a gaussian vector.
